# Adding values using PIG

Tags: apache-pig

I have a list of names and counts for males and females. Looking like this

ABEL    32898   82

CALLAN  1087    868

What is the best way in Pig to count up the total number of males and the total number of females?

Answer (score 3):

Have a look to the [GROUP ALL](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.8.1/piglatin_ref2.html#GROUP) operation:

```
data = LOAD 'data' AS (name:CHARARRAY, males_count:INT, females_count:INT);
data_all = GROUP data ALL;
counts = FOREACH data_all GENERATE SUM(data.males_count) AS tot_males, SUM(data.females_count) AS tot_females;
```